# Specify spinner while loading content with Rails UJS

Tags: javascript, jspinner

I'm using Rails UJS to load partials into a container depending on the link I click. I've got everything working (see my answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863164/rails-3-link-to-partial-with-for-loop-inside) for code) but I'd like to add a spinner while the content is loading. How can I go about doing this? I found a brief example in Simone Carletti's [post on UJS](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) but can't seem to implement it properly.

**Here's the HTML generated:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_reviews" class="active" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_about" class="inactive" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_credits" class="inactive" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">Credits</a></li>
    <li><span id="loading">Loading...</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    # load data from partials here
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll take this into a new question.

Comment: Doesn't really matter to me; I'm just sayin'. Still, without knowing what's happening, if there's anything in the Firebug console, blah blah blah, it's much harder to help.

Comment: No you're right. I appreciate it - helps me ask better, more-informed questions!

Comment: Asking the right question is often harder than answering it!

Comment: So true. I attempted to ask it in another question though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949978/showing-spinner-for-rails-3-ujs-gets-type-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this SO answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933529/rails-3-ujs-driver-events), but the easiest thing to do is to bind to the `ajax:before` and `ajax:after` events to show/hide the spinner.

Whether to do this via the `javascript_event_tag` or by binding in an external JS file is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated this with more code to show what I've tried.