# Showing spinner for Rails 3 UJS gets Type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three links in my Rails 3 app that load information in the container beneath them using UJS. To complete the experience I want to display a bit of 'Loading...' text while the information loads. So I used some jQuery from Simone Carletti's [post](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) to try to accomplish it. Depending on the jQuery, though, two different things happen when the first link is clicked. (In both scenarios, nothing happens when the other two are clicked.)

- Given the code below I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#tabs-1").js(data)')`

So to fix that I change my jQuery to `$("#tabs-1").html(data);`. Then:

- TypeError goes away
- 'Loading...' doesn't show
- Clicking my first link renders all sorts of unformatted, extraneous code like:

  - $( "#tabs-1" ).html( "
    \n Text:</h4>\n 
    \n
    text.</li>\n </div>\n</div>\n

The HTML generated:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_reviews" class="active" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">Cred</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_about" class="inactive" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profiles/1/profile_credits" class="inactive" data-remote="true" id="profile_loader">Credits</a></li>
    <span id="loading">Loading...</span>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    # load info here
  </div>
</div>
```

**An example of my `profiles_controller.rb` action that loads information:**

```
def profile_about
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => nil }
  end
end
```

**My profile_about.js.erb:**

```
$( "#tabs-1" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render (:partial => "profile_about" ) ) %>" );
```

**My application.js:**

```
$(function() {
  var toggleLoading = function() { $("span#loading").toggle() };
  $("#profile_loader")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      $("#tabs-1").js(data);
    });
});
```

**In my CSS:**

```
span#loading {
    float:right;
    padding:10px 5px;
    color:#666666;
}
```

**In my `<head>`:**

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1316133561" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1316133957" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ujs.js?1316133561" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1317960952" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity-token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="k1RB3GSMFweZ&#47;ty9haXTCWxYTOZB4DxQ90uEGTIhNo8="/>
```

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the respond_to format.js and format.xml and keep only format.html, remove the profile_about.js.erb, and keep the binding as .html(data), the console says:

```
ActionView:MissingTemplate (Missing template profiles/profile_about with {:handlers=>[:rxml, :builder, :rjs, :erb, :rhtml], :locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html] in view paths "/Users/me/Desktop/app/views", "/Users/me/Desktop/app/vendor/plugins/paperclip/app/views"): 
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:87:in 'profile_about' #format.html
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:86:in 'profile_about' #the respond_to to |format|

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by replacing the jQuery I was using (above) with jQuery found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery). It is *much* simpler than the jQuery I was working off of.

```
$(function() {
    $('#loading')
        .hide() // hide initially
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        })
        .ajaxStop(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        })
});
```

I also made a few minor changes to the code in my question above to make it work. In particular I removed: `display:none` in my css, and format.html and format.xml in my controller action.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have three links with the same ID; this is invalid HTML and will cause problems.

Not sure what you were trying with the `.js` thing; I don't even think that's a jQuery method.

You can do this either with JS, or with HTML, but I wouldn't recommend both--remove the xml and js respond_to, leave only the html. Remove the JS erb file.

In the "ajax:success" binding, keep it as `.html(data)`.

That should be all you need to do, assuming everything else is set up correctly.

Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Well, looks like I don't have everything set up correctly. Removing the `respond_to` format.js (and the js.erb files) no longer renders the partials after clicking the links.

Comment: @tvalent2 Anything in the console? What version of Rails? My test also renders a partial, although I don't *think* that would matter. And you're definitely using jQuery (not Prototype)?

Comment: @tvalent Rake routes shows what you expect? Template in the right place?

Comment: @tvalent2 Put it on github; I'll take a look--it's all working fine for me. It's also best if you answer all the questions I ask instead of just one or two, 'cuz then I have to ask again, and that's boring.